# Hide popup when clicking outside it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This piece of code shows a popup. I want this popup disappear when we click anywhere in the screen except within the popup area. I tried many things but the results were not as expected. Can someone help me out with this?
Can I use  feature through jQuery in that way I could call the home page i.e "a href ="#"?

```css
#container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  /* complimenting your modal colors */
}

#container2:target {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}

.reveal-modal {
  position: absolute;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0baa16;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal">
    ........
    <a href="#">Close Modal</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not a modal. Have you forgotten to include all the relevant CSS and JS in the question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am new to stack . I needed this feature in my website therefore I came here to find the solution to this . My comfort zone is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener on your whole document that hides your container. Because the container is part of your document, you then need to stop a click on that container to bubble up and trigger the event on your document.

```js
$(document).on('click', function(){
 $('#exampleModal').hide();
});

$('#exampleModal').on('click', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.reveal-modal {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
background:#0baa16;
    width:450px;
    left:50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal">
    
</div>
```

Comment: The popup should be able to reappear when click on the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

you can you document click event for this using jQuery, check below code :

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
    el = e.target;
    if ($(el).attr("id") != "exampleModal" && !$(el).parents('#exampleModal').length){
        $('#exampleModal').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  /* complimenting your modal colors */
}

#container2:target {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}

.reveal-modal {
  position: absolute;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0baa16;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal">
    ........
    <a href="#">Close Modal</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

may be this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and I builded an example that you can close your "popup".

The basic idea to close de modal is to test if your mouse it is hover or not on the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click(function(){
    if(!$('#exampleModal').is(':hover'))
      $('#exampleModal').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
}

.reveal-modal {
  position: fixed;
  height: 350px;
  background: #0baa16;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal">
  </div>
</div>
```